Issue creating configurable product using bulk import via web API
I am trying to import products using Magentos web api. Specifically the bulk import endpoints.
I have no issue creating and editing the products, my issue however is when I try to add the options to the configurable product.
I have been following Magento guide on this but I can't get the options to be added.
My code
$headers = array('Content-Type:application/json','Authorization:Bearer 
    '.$adminToken);

$conf_options_json = '[{
                     "sku": "MS-Champ",
                     "option": {
                        "attribute_id": "144",
                        "label": "Size",
                        "position": 0,
                        "is_use_default": true,
                        "values": [
                         {
                           "value_index": 167
                         },
                         {
                           "value_index": 168
                         },
                         {
                           "value_index": 169
                         }
                        ]
                     }
                }]';

$this->curlPost($ch, $url. "rest/all/async/bulk/V1/configurable-products/bySku/options", "POST", $conf_options_json, $headers);

private function curlPost($ch, $url, $requestType, $data,$headers){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    if($data)
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $requestType);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    print_r(json_decode($response));
    return;
}

The result
[configurable_product_options] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 309
                            [attribute_id] => 144
                            [label] => Size
                            [position] => 0
                            [values] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [product_id] => 2091
                        )

                )

I can see the super attribute is generated in catalog_product_super_attribute for the product but the values are still empty.

My eav_attribute_option_value table looks like this. The values I want to use have the option_ids I provide when creating the options. Just to be sure I was using the correct value I also tried creating the options using the value_id in this table
# value_id, option_id, store_id, value
'222',      '167',     '0',      'S'
'224',      '168',     '0',      'M'
'226',      '169',     '0',      'L'

I am at a complete loss as to why this is not working. I have been searching around and can see that a lot of people have had the same issue but still haven't found any solution.
